# Run a single test file using Node js Mocha

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js

All my tests are under test folder and when I give `npm test` all the tests are getting executed. Now I am trying to run my test scripts by file or by it's describe. I have the following in my package.json

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "set NODE_ENV=test&& nyc --reporter=html --reporter=text mocha 'test/**/*.js' --exit --timeout 7000"}
```

When I give `npm test --grep 'filename / describe / it'` it is not picking up the given input instead I'm getting the following warning `Warning: Cannot find any files matching pattern "given filename / describe /it"` even though given input matches.

My filename pattern is `filename.test.js` and the folder structure is like `test\***\filename.test.js`

Can anyone guide me on what I'm missing on this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to include the `grep` option within the `npm` command:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "set NODE_ENV=test&& nyc --reporter=html --reporter=text mocha 'test/**/*.js' --exit --timeout 7000 --grep"
}
```

Then call it with:

```
npm run test <name of test>
```

Comment: Can we run a more than one file using this command "npm run test <name of test1, name of test2>" ?
Whenever I am going to run a test I would need an global test to run along with it.
Is that possible?

Comment: @eol running test by changing script like this is not giving test result in the desired form, it is not showing how many test is passing and failing in the file instead it shows table with columns `% Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s`

Comment: @SingaSelvaSankarM: to run more than one file, you can pass a RegExp to [`--grep`](https://mochajs.org/api/mocha#grep) option. Actually, simply separating the test names by a pipe `|` seems to be enough: `npm run test -- --grep "nameOfTest1 | nameOfTest2"`

Answer (score 0):

You are simply hitting the issue that flags and options (arguments that start with dashes) are consumed by the `npm` command (it assumes it is an option for itself). Place a special double dash option `--` before, to tell `npm` that they are meant for the underlying command, rather than itself:

```bash
npm run test -- --grep "filename / describe / it"
```

[npm-run-script > Description](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/commands/npm-run-script#description):

> Use `--` to pass `-`-prefixed flags and options which would otherwise be parsed by npm.
>
> For example:
>
> `npm run test -- --grep="pattern"`

That way, your normal `npm run test` script also works without argument at all (whereas if you include `--grep` at the end and try calling it as-is, it fails with message "Error: Not enough arguments following: grep").